# Need steps to setup WSO2 ESB code base in eclipse

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Can any one please let me know the steps to setup the code base in eclipse.I wish to debug few components features. Please let me know the package or structure how i can find the source code of a specific component or mediator ?

Thanks in advance.

---

Landing into below error when trying to build Enrich code

C:\Enrich_Workspace>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/wso2/carbon/mediators/3.2.0/mediators-3.2.0.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:enrich-mediator:3.2.0 (C:\Enrich_Workspace\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.wso2.carbon:mediators:pom:3.2.0 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

Comment: what is the version of the ESB you are using ? what are the components you want to debug ?

Comment: Im using ESB 4.0.3 (Latest), want to debug Enrich mediator.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the source code from here using SVN https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/carbon/3.2.0/components/mediators/enrich/ .

Build the source using Maven 2. Then import the project to Eclipse.

Comment: I was able to see the SVN tree.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please help me on setting up teh complete ESB workspace ?

Comment: Then you can try downloading the source distribution of ESB http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/ and importing it to your eclipse workspace